# Hapi.js -- Set X-Authorization header

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I would like to implement X-Authorization to my routes in Hapi.js. So when I make a request, I will create a X-Auth header and I would like Hapi to check it before allowing some code execution:

Based on this code example from Hapi documentaiton, how Do I implement it?

```
server.route({
method: 'GET',
path: '/hello/{user?}',
handler: function (request, reply) {
    const user = request.params.user ? encodeURIComponent(request.params.user) : 'stranger';
    reply('Hello ' + user + '!');
},
config: {
    description: 'Say hello!',
    notes: 'The user parameter defaults to \'stranger\' if unspecified',
    tags: ['api', 'greeting']
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `headers` property of `request` object to get `X-Authorization` value. However, it should be `request.headers['x-authorization']` (all lowercase).

Please refer to http://hapijs.com/api#request-properties for document.

The reason of "Why request header name should be lower-cased" is: In Node.js, `request` object belong to class `http.IncomingMessage`, whose header names are lower-cased. Please refer to https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/http.html#http_message_headers for more information.

Answer (score 3):

hapi lets you access the request headers in your route handler by using `request.headers`, like this:

```
server.route({  
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/hello/{user?}',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    const headers = request.headers   // <-- get request headers

    const auth = headers['x-authorization']

    // use the auth header value for further processing

    reply({ your: data })
  }
})
```

If you need more details, you can read more in this tutorial on [how to access request headers in hapi](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-access-request-headers).

Additionally, if you need to check the `X-Authorization` header on every incoming request, it would be efficient to [create a dedicated plugin](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-create-your-own-custom-plugin).

Hope that helps!